# Accessing parent window from child window?

Tags: javascript

I have a main window named worklistManager.jsp.
worklistManager.jsp has a pop up window named processManager.jsp.
Again, processManager.jsp has another pop up window, named eventLog.jsp.
Once again eventLog.jsp has a pop up window named eventUsers.jsp.

eventUsers.jsp has a dojox/grid/DataGrid and a button. After selecting a particular row in the grid, then clicking the button, it has to place the value into the textbox of eventLog.jsp after closing eventUsers.jsp.

So far, I have tried the script below to accomplish this, but it's not working as I hoped.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getEventLogUserSelect(){
    if(dijit.byId('dynamiceventusergridCWUSER')){
        var selctedItem = dijit.byId('dynamiceventusergridCWUSER').selection.getSelected();
        if(selctedItem.length){
            dojo.forEach(selctedItem, function(selectedItem){
                if(selectedItem !== null){
                    dojo.forEach(dijit.byId('dynamiceventusergridCWUSER').store.getAttributes(selectedItem), function(attribute){
                        var value = dijit.byId('dynamiceventusergridCWUSER').store.getValues(selectedItem, attribute);
                        if(attribute == "USERID"){
                            window.opener.SetValue(value);
                            window.close();
                        }

                    });
                }
            });
            //alert("grid row selected");
        }else{
            alert("grid row not selected");
        }
    }
    if(gbshowgridFlag==false){
        alert("grid not loaded");
    }
}
function SetValue(val){
       var txt = document.getElementById('CWPROCESSEVENTLOG.USER_ID');
       txt.value = val;

    }
</script>
```

Comment: can anyone give answer for above question?